# Why does Python's create_autospec() trigger property getters on underscore-prefixed field access and why twice?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm using Python's `unittest.mock.create_autospec()` to create a mock object of a class. I noticed an odd behavior - when I try to access the underscore-prefixed field directly (i.e., `mock._val`), it triggers the getter of the property val. I was under the impression that accessing the underscore-prefixed field should not trigger the getter at all.

Moreover, the getter method is called twice. Is this expected behavior? And if so, why is it designed this way?

Here's an example that reproduces the behavior:

```
from unittest.mock import create_autospec

def test_strange_behavior():
    class MyCls:
        def __init__(self):
            self._val = None

        @property
        def val(self):
            print("Inside Get")
            return self._val

        @val.setter
        def val(self, value):
            print("Inside Set")
            self._val = value

    mock = create_autospec(spec=MyCls(), spec_set=True, )
    print("Before")
    print(mock._val)  # This line triggers the getter method for 'val'
    print("After")
```

```
$ python --version
Python 3.10.6
$ pip list | grep pytest
pytest                7.1.3
```

Output:

```
$ pytest my_test.py -s
============================================================================================================================== test session starts ===============================================================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.6, pytest-7.1.3, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/david/PycharmProjects/test
plugins: Faker-13.3.4, postgresql-5.0.0
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

my_test.py Inside Get  # First call
Inside Get  # Second call
Before
<NonCallableMagicMock name='mock._val' id='140286340235120'>
After
.

=============================================================================================================================== 1 passed in 0.02s ================================================================================================================================
```

Comment: In my system the getter method is not trigger.